# Cannot resolve symbol newInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return  new CryptoListChildFragment.newInstance();
        }else {
            return  new CryptoListChildFavFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }  


public class CryptoListChildFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private CoinAdapter mAdapter;
private NetworkService retrofit;
private Coin[] coinList;
private FrameLayout root;

public CryptoListChildFragment(){

}

public static CryptoListChildFragment newInstance() {
    CryptoListChildFragment myFragment = new CryptoListChildFragment();
    return myFragment;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crypto_list_child, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.coin_list);
    mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_coins);
    root = view.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    return view;
}
```

I have newInstance() method but it says 'cannot resolve symbol newInstance'.I am trying to call it from a FragmentPageAdapter.I created a new Fragment also byt again same error.

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: check what version you had import in both fragment.

Comment: You are accessing static method with instance

Comment: @HemantParmar both fragments are support-fragment 27.1.1

Comment: yes @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 2):

It must be :

```
....
if (i==1){
   return CryptoListChildFragment.newInstance()
....
```

BTW:
You should not create a new variable here:

```
public static CryptoListChildFragment newInstance() {
    CryptoListChildFragment myFragment = new CryptoListChildFragment();
    return myFragment;
}
```

return the instance in one line:

```
public static CryptoListChildFragment newInstance() {
    return new CryptoListChildFragment();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,it works.

Comment: @PrateekKumar You are welcome